# How to handle suggested edits with no Edit Summary?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, ethics

[This suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/241842) appears to have no edit summary whatsoever - the proper HTML source is:

```
<span class="revision-comment" title="comment on this suggested edit">                                    </span>
```

So as you can see by viewing the characters it's the infamous "double space".

How should we deal with this? If the suggestion is good guess it's better to approve it, but should we comment on one of the suggestor's posts asking him nicely to behave? Or something else?

Edit: for those with more than 2K+ rep - this field **is** mandatory:

[image: screenshot]

So avoiding it is kind of tricking the system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suggested edits have a mandatory revision comment, in contrast to edits by 2k+ users who can omit the edit comment. If there is an empty comment there, the user intentionally circumvented that check, which isnt't exactly a point in their favor.

If the edit was a good and complete edit I would still approve it. If it's not obvious why something was changed I would just reject it, or if it is otherwise a bad edit. I personally would be likely more strict with borderline edits than usually, as I don't think evasion of the enforced revision comment is something we should encourage.

Answer (score 6):

If the edit is a good edit approve it, if it's a bad edit reject it.

Obviously if there's no comment you might be more inclined to reject if there's no obvious reason why the edit was made. For example if a link or image was changed unless you know *why* from the comment it could be just vandalism.

There's nothing that forces anyone to enter anything sensible in the summary, but not having a sensible comment is something that will probably affect your decision making (and quite rightly too).

I suppose it all comes down to the actual edit. Does it make sense even without the comment? If so accept it.

Comment: I don't think that's true, I remember there being a minimum length for suggested edits, though it still doesn't force anyone to enter anything there that makes sense.

Comment: @Fabian - ah, you may be right. There's no requirement for normal edits which is what made me think there wasn't for suggested ones.

Comment: Of course nothing is *forcing*, but should we just ignore such things?

Comment: The comment in this case seems to consist entirely of whitespace, so it seems pretty easy to evade the check.

Comment: @Fabian ordinary white space is checked and trimmed, he used       such     characters..